# Worklight 5.0.6 wipes out native customizations in shell

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I upgraded my environment to v5.0.6. Problem is that everytime i start Eclipse it does this:

> [2013-04-19 18:38:41] FWLST1017I: [AppShell] upgraded to the latest
>   platform version.

When this upgrade takes place, it reverts my templates and adds class files to the iphone\native folder and removes the plugins I configured in the shell:

1. Removes all my custom plugins from components/AppShell/iphone/native/Classes
2. Resets project.pbxproj.wltemplate.wluser to stock removing includes for my classes
3. Resets config.xml.wluser removing all mappings to my plugins

It also always shows at the end of the upgrade process:

> Failed to upgrade Worklight project 'AppMobile' to the latest platform
>   version. [null]

Is that why it keeps running the upgrade and reverting my changes?

Comment: Using the sample application from 5.0.5 and upgrading it to 5.0.6, there are no failures. It seems you may have hit a use case where the upgrad process fails; if possible please edit your question with a download link to your Worklight project (zipped).

Comment: I would love to, but not sure if i can get the customer to sign off on that.  For right now, it looks like i might just roll back to 5.0.5 and see if i can recover the environment.  Because even after a reintegrated our native plugin files, the compiled IOS app would never fire ondeviceready and stays stuck on the loading screen.

Comment: Sounds like you're an IBMer... find me on SameTime or Lotus Notes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you have some .wluser files, which means that something is wrong with your project.

Can you please let me know whether the problem still exists and whether you still have those files in you project?

Comment: We got over this on when we moved to version 6.0.  I created a new environment and imported the project.  After that i recreated the plugins and configurations on the native folder.